# Mutual Inductance in more than two objects

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

I was working on problems with mutual inductance out of Griffiths and it seems we always talk about the mutual inductance between two objects.  It seems however, that in principle, we should be able to find the mutual inductance between three objects such that:
$M_{123}=\Phi_{12}I_3=\Phi_{13}I_2=\Phi_{23}I_1$

However, thinking about how to find the flux from different objects seems like an issue, I haven't been able to find anything, what I am picturing is something like a delta transformer where none of the coils are electrically connected and are instead causing induced currents on each other.

How might this situation vary if there was current in one wire vs. two of the wires?

Comment: What is $\Phi_{12}$ and other $\Phi$'s? Mutual electromagnetic induction is a phenomenon that can and is usually broken down into sum of pair effects, where body A experiences something due to another body B. There is no point in introducing third body in a pair effect A-B. This third body is accounted for by considering another pairs A-C, B-C.

Comment: I was using $\Phi_{12}$ to mean the combined flux from objects 1 and 2, I think that might have been ambigious.  It seems to me that this third body will still have some affect on the overall mutual inductance of the other two.  When you say that we can consider these other pairs, does this mean we can sum mutual inductance linearly for multiple bodies?

Comment: If $\Phi_{12}$ is flux through circuit 3 due to circuits 1,2, why would you multiply it by current $I_3$? Flux in circuit 3 due to two bodies 1,2 is sum of fluxes due to each body: $\Phi_{12} = \Phi_1 + \Phi_2$. These fluxes have nothing to do with current $I_3$, they are determined by currents $I_1$, $I_2$ and geometrical properties of all three circuits.